# ZEND Left Join Distinct Query

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework

I have this `SQL`query:

```
select * 
from locations 
left join (select location_id, name as occupied 
           from meetings 
           where start < $value1 and end > $value2 limit 1) m 
           on locations.id = m.location_id;
```

Every location from `locations` table has many meetings, and every meeting belongs to a specific location. Every meeting has a start time and an end time. With that query, i want to get all the locations from the database and add a `booked` column to everyone, and if the location is occupied in the given interval, the `occupied` column's value would be the overlapping's meeting name.

The `SQL` query returns exactly what I want (ex. `Location 1, Location 2, Location 3, etc`).

I want to use the same query but in my ZEND model. Now I have

```
$model = new Model_Location();
$m = new Model_Meeting();
$model->getSelect()
      ->joinLeft(
           "meetings as m", 
           "m.location_id = $model.id AND m.start < $value1 AND m.end > $value2", 
           array('occupied' => "m.name"));
```

which returns what I expect, but for every overlapping meeting, I get an entry it's lcoation, resulting in `Location 1, Location 1, Location 2, Location 2, Location 2, Location 3, etc`. How can I get only the distinct values? I know that `limit` isn' present in my zend query, but I don't know where to use it. I tried after `joinLeft`, and before it, but in those cases it limit's my model to just 1 entry, not just the distinct ones. I also tried `->distinct()` but didn't work either.

Comment: Have you tried writing the query so it doesnt use the subquery and just joins directly to meetings?

Comment: Are you saying that I should use `getSelect()->query(.....)` ?

Comment: No just saying if the issue is the subquery you might have more success rewriting the query as below:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GROUP BY is what you are looking for, so :

```
$model = new Model_Location();
$m = new Model_Meeting();
$model->getSelect()
      ->joinLeft(
           "meetings as m", 
           "m.location_id = $model.id AND m.start < $value1 AND m.end > $value2", 
           array('occupied' => "m.name"));
      ->group('$model.id')
```

Side note : your raw sql query is not exactly the same as your zend one, since in your raw query you're doing a subquery, and in the zend one you're doing a direct join (which is better).

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you very much!